# Unable to get OpenTypeExtensionProperty for event using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

For one of our application, I am trying to get Extensions for an event using the following code in C#:

```
var result = graphServiceClient.User[userid].Calendar.Events[eventid].Extensions.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

However, I am getting following exception:

> Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
> Message: The OData request is not supported.
> ClientRequestId: f7a44c2f-ca79-4f79-9726-2cdc98d87e00

I found the above code in few of the questions posted on stackoverflow.

We need to add and get opentype extensions by any means. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i used Microsoft Graph explorer to [create the event and add opentypeextension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) to it:

[image]

Then [get the opentypeextensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for the above event using its id:

[image]

Code will look like this:

```html
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var extension = await graphClient.Me.Events["'AAMkAGRlNWYmM5YjIzNTRhMwBGAAAAAAA-AAA='"].Extensions["Com.Contoso.Referral"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The above worked for me, however in my case I wanted to check all outlook events for the specific extension and in case the extension is not present in any one of the events, I was get the following error:

> Code: ErrorItemNotFound
> Message: The specified object was not found in the store.
> ClientRequestId: a65d0d31-123b-4834-9bec-8d471d22b6e0

To resolve above, while iterating through all events I added the code for fetching extension in try catch block and added following code in catch block to continue the loop in case we have above exception

```
if (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(ServiceException) &&
                    ex.InnerException.Message.Contains("Code: ErrorItemNotFound"))
                    continue;
```

Anyways my issue is resolved now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad that the above helped..!!